# Safe Outdoor Algae Remover

Tags: cleaning

I live in an apartment building and our balcony has a lot of green algae (or mould?) on the glass and concrete from being wet. What is a good way to clean this off? I want something that is safe for the environment and other people as I don't want to wash harsh chemicals onto the balconies below us. I am based in Canada so it would need to be something I can source here or from the US

Comment: Bleach is safe.  Don't need buckets of it.  Hydrogen peroxide is suppose to work also.  So when washing the floors, can do the outside at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the safest product is [Wet and forget](https://www.lowes.com/pd/Wet-and-Forget-128-fl-oz-Multi-surface-Outdoor-Cleaner/999972902?cm_mmc=shp-_-c-_-prd-_-lwn-_-ggl-_-LIA_HDW_127_Cleaning-_-999972902-_-local-_-0-_-0&gad_source=1&gclid=Cj0KCQjw-_mvBhDwARIsAA-Q0Q4l942NuSlkkt9XgySE5lpsSiYCClP_2zVfZhml6u4MrDzLZPZ55O8aAnbiEALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds).

The downside is it takes time to clean the mold and mildew. However it does have residual properties and will last fairly long.

The use and care manual is [here](https://pdf.lowes.com/productdocuments/29d6fdfe-9a91-402b-b708-9fd1db524116/08539537.pdf).